# Can I RAID 0 two secondary drives without involving my primary disk?

Tags: hard-drive, performance, raid, raid-0

I have a 60GB SSD as my primary OS drive.  It has a few core applications on it, but because of the size, I don't want to put too much on it.

My intention is to get two 1TB drives to use as storage for almost everything else and stripe them to improve performance.  Obviously, I want to keep the SSD isolated and out of this RAID arrangement.

I've never set up RAID before and I'm unsure whether this can even be done?

If it's relevant, my motherboard is an *Asus P8H67-M-PROV3* and claims full support for RAID.

Can I do this?  Is it a straightforward process or will I be playing with fire?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is straightforward. I'm not familiar with that particular motherboard, but generally speaking you boot into the RAID bios, select which drives you would like to use as a RAID device. You would have to install the drivers for your RAID support on the SSD, but this is eminently doable and simpler than having your boot drive as a member of the RAID group.

EDIT: Actually, the only complication would be what your OS is and the driver support for said OS. If it's a modern flavor of Windows, you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks, and yes - Windows 7 64-bit, so shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Yeah, shouldn't be an issue. What you're looking to do is just about the simplest RAID setup I can think of. Just make sure you back up.

Comment: Excellent, thanks.  And luckily - not much to back up at the moment!

Comment: Just to be clear, I'm confident that emgee's advice to back up was a reference to the fact that a RAID0 array of two disks has TWICE the failure rate of the individual member disks.

Comment: Slartibartfast, that is correct. And that striping volumes will delete anything currently on them.